# Error: Column `memory_scaled` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tags: r, scale

I've scaled a vector with working memory capacity scores as follows:

```
data$memory_scaled = scale(data$memory_numeric, center=T, scale=T)
```

I then want to take a subset of the original data using:

```
data3 = filter(data, rt < 3000)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Column `memory_scaled` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list
```

I've read that the problem is that the scale() function adds extra arguments. Indeed, when I do `summary(data)` the name of the variable has an extra "V1" to the name (`memory_scaled.V1`). Is there any way to work with a scaled variable avoiding these problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scale` returns matrix, which has two dimensions.

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10)
dat$col2 <- scale(dat$col1)

lapply(dat, class)
#$col1
#[1] "integer"

#$col2
#[1] "matrix"
```

A workaround would be this

```
dat$col2 <- c(scale(dat$col1))
```

Now `col2` is a numeric vector, i.e. 1d atomic vector and `dplyr::filter` works as expected

```
dplyr::filter(dat, col1 < 4)
#  col1       col2
#1    1 -1.4863011
#2    2 -1.1560120
#3    3 -0.8257228
```